# Proof of the Usual Topology on R

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm trying to prove that the usual topology on R is in fact a topology for R. I've read through a few books on topology and most of them seem to skip over the proof and list it as "trivial". My math skills are obviously lacking because I'm stumped! I'm trying to prove the following three things:

1. That R and the empty set are elements of the usual topology
2. That the union of any two elements is an element of the usual topology
3. That the intersection of any two elements is an element of the usual topology

Of these, 3 to me seems the easiest to prove because if two elements don't overlap, the answer is the empty set, otherwise it is given by the interval that the two elements overlap.

I'm having a few issues with 1 and 2 though. Specifically:

Why is the empty set in the usual topology? I can't find a value x in R or e > 0 such that the empty set = x +- e?

Likewise, why is R in the usual topology? For example, take x = 0 and e = (abstractly) "the biggest number in R". Then we have the interval from -"the biggest number" to +"the biggest number", but by definition that cannot include "the biggest number" so isn't R?

By this logic, it seems that maybe a better definition for the usual topology is not only all intervals in R, but also R and the empty set as well?

Lastly, I'm struggling to prove that the union of two elements is also in the usual topology. Consider the intervals (1, 2) and (3, 4). The union of these two isn't an interval, hence shouldn't be a part of the usual topology?

Now obviously several centuries worth of mathematicians are going to be vastly more correct than me (and that's something I can actually prove!) so my big question is... where am I going wrong? Is it in my understanding of the usual topology, of topologies in general or in my logic?

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, I should have mentioned the definition of "usual topology". The usual topology T is defined such that that O is an element of T if and only if for all x in O there exists an e > 0 such that the interval (x - e, x + e) is a subset of O.

Comment: Well, first make yourself clear: What *is* the usual topology? A set $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ is open iff ...?

Comment: By usual topology do you mean unions of intervals? Then the empty set is $(a,a)$, or if you don't like that the empty union. If you like neither of these, then specify the empty set is in.

Comment: Also your definition of a topology seems to be wrong. The second axiom should be: an *arbitrary* elements, i.e. open sets, is again an element, i.e. open.

Comment: Plus the third axiom is not limited to two sets: any finite intersection of open sets should be open.

Comment: @Lost But that follows from having it just for two sets.

Comment: Edit: I meant to say an *arbitrary union* of elements.

Comment: This seems suspiciously like a homework problem from a class I'm taking on Coursera.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First a reminder of the definition of a topology:

> **Definition 1:**
>   A collection $\tau$ of subsets of some set $X$ is called a *topology* on $X$, iff
>
> - $\emptyset, X\in \tau$
> - An arbitrary union of sets in $\tau$ is again in $\tau$.
> - A finite intersection of sets in $\tau$ is again in $\tau$.

Now your other mistake is that you are not making yourself aware of how the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is actually *defined*:

> **Definition 2:** A set $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is called *open* iff for every $x\in U$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset U$.

So for instance, $\emptyset$ is really open by that definition, since it *does not have any elements* $x$ for which there would have to exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that (..).

Also, $\mathbb{R}$ is tautologically open by that definition, since the sets $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ are always contained in $\mathbb{R}$, no matter what $x,\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ are exactly.

Now let us take an (arbitrarily large, possibly uncountable) index set $I$ and for every $i\in I$ an open set $U_i\subset\mathbb{R}$. Consider the set

$$U=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$$

We have to show that $U$ is open. Therefore take some $x\in U$, but then $x\in U_i$ for some $i\in I$. But $U_i$ is open, hence (.. can you finish the thought?)

To check that finite intersections of open sets are again open, it suffices to check this for the intersection of two open sets. Let $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}$ be open. We claim that then $$W=U\cap V$$ is open as well.

So let $x\in W$. Then $x\in U$ and $x\in V$. But $U$ and $V$ are open, hence there exists (.. can you finish it from here?).

Comment: Thanks - this helps a lot! I understand that the empty set is an element of T because we don't *need* to find an e because there are no x. Likewise for R, all x and e are from R, so all of R must be included. For the union of sets, I think here my mistake was thinking that it had to be a continuous open set... but if we join together a bunch of open sets, as you say, we're going to get another open set. For your last point, I think U and V are open so there exists an e > 0 such that x - e and x + e are an element of W?

Comment: @user3081739 Yes, that is what we have to prove. But first there exist only $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset U$ and $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset V$. Now assume wlog. that $\epsilon\le \delta$. Then $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset (x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset V$. Therefore $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset U\cap V=W$.

Comment: @user3081739 Also please note: the notation $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset U$ does **not** mean that $x-\epsilon$ and $x+\epsilon$ are elements of $U$. It means that the open interval (i.e. all the numbers strictly greater than $x-\epsilon$ and strictly smaller than $x+\epsilon$) is contained in $U$.

Comment: Thanks again! I think the bit that is confusing me is that, as you say, x - e and x + e are not included, so my brain is saying that I should be able to find some numbers a = x - e, b = x + e which are *not* included in an interval... but they must be included in another interval because the topology contains *all* *possible* unions. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Your questions seem to center around intervals of the form $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$. Such intervals are indeed open. However, the collection of such intervals is not a topology, for precisely the reasons you've stated! It doesn't include the empty set, the whole line, or the union $(1,2)\cup(3,4)$.

So, the usual topology is *not* defined as the collection of such intervals. Instead, the topology is defined as the collection of *all possible unions* of such intervals. Formally, one says that the intervals of the form $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ are a *[basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29)* for the topology. It's important not to get  the basis confused with the whole topology.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I think you've nailed my mistake!