# Rudin, topology on $\mathbb{R}$ how to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The Rudin (real and complex analysis) says that:

> Another topological space, which we shall encounter frequently, is the
>   extended real line $[- \infty, \infty]$; its topology is defined by declaring
>   the following sets to be open: $(a, b), [ - \infty, a), (a, +\infty]$, and any
>   union of segments of this type.

My question is: "Why is this a basis for some topology on the extended real line?"
and "Why is the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by the topology generated by the given basis the standard topology?",

I tried to look in the munkres book for a proof, but I can't find it.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question please? What is "the topology in $\mathbb{R}$" you refer to? And why now the reals and not the extended reals?

Comment: Put another way, is the question, "Why is this a basis for some topology on the extended real line?", or "Why is the subspace topology on $\Bbb R$ induced by the topology generated by the given basis the standard topology?", or something else altogether?

Comment: The one i quoted from the book i mentioned (i mentioned what the book says). The quote is from page 9 section 1.4.

Comment: @Travis yes, that's the question.

Comment: The first or the second question?

Comment: @Travis, i would say both of them.

Comment: Perhaps add that to your question, then.

Comment: You may like to refer this one - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656965/proof-of-the-usual-topology-on-r

Comment: Look up the *order topology* in Munkres to familiarize yourself with this construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general a collection $\mathcal B\subseteq\wp(X)$ serves as base of topology on $X$ if:

- $\bigcup\mathcal B=X$.
- Every intersection $B_1\cap B_2$ where $B_1,B_2\in \mathcal B$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

Under these conditions the collection $\tau:=\{\bigcup\mathcal B'\mid \mathcal B'\subseteq\mathcal B\}$ is a topology on $X$ and $\mathcal B$ is a base for it.

If $\mathcal C\subseteq\wp(X)$ is any subcollection of $\wp(X)$ and $\mathcal B$ is defined as the collection of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal C$, then $\mathcal B$ will satisfy the mentioned conditions and $\tau$ as defined above will be the smallest topology that contains $\mathcal C$.

This under the convention that $\bigcap\varnothing:=X$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? i'm quite confused... how do you exploit the structure of the open sets i've given?

Comment: At the moment time lacks (I will be off after this comment). The collection of sets of the form $[-\infty,a),(a,+\infty],(a,b)$ form a base $\mathcal B$. You can check that the conditions that I mention are satisfied. The open sets ($\tau$ in my answer) are unions of these sets.

Comment: Is it a my impression or the formulas on your post show up in a messy way?

Comment: I am not judge of your impressions. Do you understand what I am saying in my comment? I answered your first question in a general way. An answer to your second question lacks.

Comment: *Any* collection of subsets $\mathcal C$ of the extended real line serves as a *subbasis* of a topology. If the collection satisfies some conditions (see my answer for that) then is not only a subbasis but also a *basis* for that topology. The collection of sets mentioned in your question (and my comment) indeed satisfies these conditions. So this answers: "Why is this a basis for some topology...?" as you asked.

Comment: So you proved that the collection of set i gave was a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: Actually for general $X$ and you can substitute here $X=[-\infty,+\infty]$. The question concerned the extended real line.

Comment: However if you proved that the collection i gave is a basis for some topology, i'm still confused because basis elements and open sets are not supposed to be the same thing. Am i missing something?

Comment: In your question I read: "declaring the following sets to be open..". A collection is mentioned. These sets together do not form a topology. It concerns the smallest topology that will contain these sets (that are declared open). At that stage the sets deserve the label "subbasis". But having a look at the sets we find that they satisfy the conditions mentioned in my answer. That means that they somehow deserve a stronger label: they form a "basis". In my answer I tried to make clear why they are called "basis" (your first question).

Comment: Ok, now another question comes up... following your answer I see that "using that subbasis you can build a topology". Since you can define different topology on a set how can I be sure that the topology given by the construction you mentioned is the one i'm looking for (which I guess is the standard topology)?

Comment: You can only be sure of one thing: the topology build like this is the *smallest* topology that contains the sets that are declared open. Our conversation grows too long. If things are not clear enough yet, then you could ask a second question, eventually with a link to this one.

Comment: Just a stupid last question, with "smallest" topology do you mean the coarsest topology you could define on the set $X = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The coarsest topology that contains the sets that are *declared* open.