# Thm: About bases for a topology on a set X

Tags: general-topology

Thm: Let $\beta$ be a nonempty collection of subsets of a set $X$. If the intersection of any finite number of members of $\beta$ is always in $\beta$ and if $\bigcup \beta$ = $X$, then $\beta$ is a base for a topology on $X$.

This is not mentioned in the book but i read that

"It is worth noting that not all bases satisfy the conditions of this theorem, for example the set of all open discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$"

Why is it so?

Comment: Its a statement of the form $A\Rightarrow B$ and the author observes that $B \Rightarrow A$ is false.

Comment: Actually it is enough (and necessary) that for each pair $B_1,B_2\in\beta$ the intersection can be written as a *union of elements* of $\beta$. Have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1616979/75923).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of two discs is not necessarily a disc, you can easily find an example if you take two intersecting discs with different centres. However, they still are a base for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: oh, yes i was thinking about all open discs with a common center.